# how to use volcano plot graph on a data frame and print it

Tags: python, graph

I need your help in using " volcano plot" , I saw that I need to import  bioinfokit using this:

`from bioinfokit import analys, visuz`

I tried to apply some codes I saw and read about,  but  couldnt understand basic things:
how can I use "volcano plot" while i have a df and I want to add a volcano plot to see the gene expression and how printing the volcano plot in a way I would be abble to see the "graph"

thanks!